# How to change the text color of the clicked row of table with css and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

In a table, I need to change the color of all the text of the row that is clicked, something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jRj8E/1/) without the background color. The same code is not working for me.

This is the code with a snippet :

```js
$("#myTable tr").on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

```css
table {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
tr td {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    color: #2C3D50;
    font-weight: 600;
}
table td .fa {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

.member > tr > td:nth-child(1) {
    border-right: none;
}

td:hover {
    background-color: #00BD9A;
    color: white;
}
    
tr .done{
    color: #F7AA25;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:70%">
        <col style="10%">
        <col style="10%">
        <col style="10%">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <i class="fa fa-eye pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pellentesque in felis <i class="fa fa-eye pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it should be `tr.done` not `tr .done` in your CSS

Comment: see here    http://jsfiddle.net/jRj8E/70/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used to this  find your `td` and define your css only `.done` class not `tr .done`

```
$("#myTable tr").on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('td').addClass("done");
});
```

```js
$("#myTable tr").on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('td').addClass("done");
});
```

```css
table {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
tr td {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    color: #2C3D50;
    font-weight: 600;
}
table td .fa {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.member > tr > td:nth-child(1) {
    border-right: none;
}

td:hover {
    background-color: #00BD9A;
    color: white;
}

.done{
    color: #F7AA25;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:70%">
        <col style="10%">
        <col style="10%">
        <col style="10%">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <i class="fa fa-eye pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pellentesque in felis <i class="fa fa-eye pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Sorry first timer here!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your jQuery as below.

1. Remove `selected` class from all rows -
2. Add `selected` class to current/selected row.

```html
$("tbody tr").click(function() {
  console.log('clicked');
  $("tbody tr").removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/jRj8E/71/).